Best way to split the query params that is present in a string and then encode
I have few strings that could be in this format:
const s1 = "https://test1.com/testPage";
const s2 = "https://test2.com/testPage?specificParam=1"
const s3 = "https://test3.com/someOtherPage?specificParam=2&restParam=3";


So when i read it in a function, I have to check if a string has query params included, if yes then I have to encode it using it window.btoa() to all the query params. If not directly redirect. Can someone assist as to how to do this?
function test(path){
   const href = window.location.origin + path;
   if(href.includes('?')){
      // split all the query params and then attach `btoa` to it and then openthe url 
       with encoded params
   }
   window.open(href, '_blank', 'no-referer');
} 


You can use the URL constructor.
const url = new URL("https://test3.com/someOtherPage?specificParam=2&restParam=3");
if (url.search) {
    // use url.search or url.searchParams
    // base64 encode each query param value
    url.search = new URLSearchParams([...url.searchParams].map(([k, v]) => [k, btoa(v)]));
}


How can I apply window. btoa on all the params?

@lrr59 Are we to assume that the original string is not encoded as a proper url?

yes its not encoded. UI has to encode it, afterall the query params are not encoded

@lrr59 You could go with url.search = new URLSearchParams(url.search.slice(1).split('&').map(p => {     const [k, v] = p.split('=');     return [k, btoa(v)]; }));, but that won't work if there are special characters in the parameter values that are not in a proper format.

there is some issue while i copy your snippet. Could you add it to the same function in the answer itself.

I am getting this, Type 'URLSearchParams' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322) when used with typescript. I used it like this,
   const redirectUrl: URL = new URL("https://test2.com/testPage?specificParam=1");
    if (redirectUrl.search) {
      redirectUrl.search = new URLSearchParams([...redirectUrl.searchParams].map(([k, v]) => [k, window.btoa(v)]));
    }
    window.open(redirectPath, '_blank', 'no-referer'); ``````

@lrr59 You may add .toString() to the end in that case, i.e. url.search = new URLSearchParams([...url.searchParams].map(([k, v]) => [k, btoa(v)])).toString();
